# Objective C Encryption CFB Mode

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm aware that in Objective C I can encrypt using AES128 through their native libraries (CommonCrypter.h). In Java, I'm encrypting using AES128 ISO-8859-1 in CFB Mode. In Objective C encoding is done through NSISOLATIN1STRINGENCODING but the problem is there's no equivalent in CFB Mode. The only modes available are: EBC padding, KCCOPTIONECBMODE and KCCOPTIONPKCS7PADDING.

I need to encrypt using AES128 with CFB Mode. Does anyone have an idea about it? 
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Apparently I always get too excited to solve my problems using the suggested answers, that I forget to mark the correct answers =)

Comment: I have made a code that can help to encrypt AES128 bit with CFB mode & no padding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997088/i-want-to-create-aes-128-using-cfb-encryption-with-no-padding-in-objective-c/37019462#37019462

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CBC can be built using ECB, conceptually it's:

```
Key K;
InitializationVector IV;
OutputDataStream OS;
Block X;

set X = IV;
for each Block B of data D:
    Block E = ECB(K, B ^ X);
    set X = E
    write E to OS
```