# AES128 encryption in IOS and php

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes

I am trying to AES128 encryption of a string or NSDictaionary, using following code

```
    NSString *str  =@"Hello";
    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *cipher = [data AES128EncryptWithKey:key];
    //After that I converts nsdata into hex string 

    NSLog(@"%@",[self hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:NO withdata:cipher]);


    -(NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
    {
        // ‘key’ should be 16 bytes for AES128
        char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
        bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

        // fetch key data
        [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

        //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
        //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
        //That’s why we need to add the size of one block here
        size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
        void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

        size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
        CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt,
                                              kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                              kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                              keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                              @"1234567812345678" /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                              [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                              buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                              &numBytesEncrypted );
        if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
        {
            //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
            return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        }

        free( buffer ); //free the buffer
        return nil;
    }


    -(NSString*)hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:(BOOL)spaces withdata:(NSData*)data
    {
        const unsigned char* bytes = (const unsigned char*)[data bytes];
        NSUInteger nbBytes = [data length];
        //If spaces is true, insert a space every this many input bytes (twice this many output characters).
        static const NSUInteger spaceEveryThisManyBytes = 4UL;
        //If spaces is true, insert a line-break instead of a space every this many spaces.
        static const NSUInteger lineBreakEveryThisManySpaces = 4UL;
        const NSUInteger lineBreakEveryThisManyBytes = spaceEveryThisManyBytes * lineBreakEveryThisManySpaces;
        NSUInteger strLen = 2*nbBytes + (spaces ? nbBytes/spaceEveryThisManyBytes : 0);

        NSMutableString* hex = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:strLen];
        for(NSUInteger i=0; i<nbBytes; ) {
            [hex appendFormat:@"%02X", bytes[i]];
            //We need to increment here so that the every-n-bytes computations are right.
            ++i;

            if (spaces) {
                if (i % lineBreakEveryThisManyBytes == 0) [hex appendString:@"\n"];
                else if (i % spaceEveryThisManyBytes == 0) [hex appendString:@" "];
            }
        }
        return hex ;
    }
```

On server side following decryption code  added

```
function decrypt($code) {
                  //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);
                  $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
                  $iv = $this->iv;

                  $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

                  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
                  $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

                  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
                  mcrypt_module_close($td);

                  return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
                }

                protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
                  $bindata = '';

                  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
                        $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
                  }

                  return $bindata;
                }
```

I problem is that on generated encrypt string not decrypting in php

WE are trying to follow [this link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php.html)

Comment: Are you including the proper IV in the decrypt?

Comment: @dbugger yes I included proper IV.

Comment: @dbugger,But I am trying for encryption not decryption..

Comment: By testing decryption, so are you sure your decryption code works?

Comment: yes,At my end If I decrypt my encrypt string,its give me original string

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997088/i-want-to-create-aes-128-using-cfb-encryption-with-no-padding-in-objective-c/37019462#37019462

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, it will decrypt & encrypt clear text in both ways using AES128 (Rijndael) with CBC and PKCS7 Padding in PHP and C using CommonCrypto in OSX/iOS and MCRYPT in PHP:

**OSX/iOS Code in C:**

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Encrypt text */

char *encryptText(const unsigned char *clearText, char myKey[20], char myIv[20]) 
{
    CCCryptorStatus status;
    unsigned char cipherKey[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    unsigned char cipherIv[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    unsigned char cipherText[strlen((const char *)clearText) + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t nEncrypted;

    for (int i=0 ; i<kCCKeySizeAES128; i++)
    {
        cipherKey[i] = myKey[i];
        cipherIv[i] = myIv[i];
    }
    
    status = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, cipherKey, kCCKeySizeAES128, cipherIv, clearText, strlen((const char *)clearText), cipherText, sizeof(cipherText), &nEncrypted);
    
    if (status != kCCSuccess) 
    {
        printf("CCCrypt() failed with error %d\n", status);
    }

    size_t cipherSize = nEncrypted;
    char *encoded_data = b64_encode((const unsigned char*)cipherText, cipherSize);

    return encoded_data;
}

/* Decrypt text */

int decode(unsigned char *dest, const char *buf) 
{
    char b[3];
    int i;
    b[2] = 0;

    for(i=0; buf[i] ;i+=2) 
    {
        b[0] = buf[i];
        b[1] = buf[i+1];
        dest[i/2] = (int) strtol(b, NULL, 0x10);
    }

    return 0;
}

char *decryptText(const unsigned char *cipherText, char myKey[20], char myIv[20]) 
{
    unsigned char cipherKey[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    unsigned char cipherIv[kCCKeySizeAES128];

    for (int i=0 ; i<kCCKeySizeAES128; i++)
    {
        cipherKey[i] = myKey[i];
        cipherIv[i] = myIv[i];
    }

    int lenKey = strlen((const char *)cipherKey);
    char hex_key[(lenKey*2)+1];
    char2hex((char *)cipherKey, hex_key);

    int lenIv = strlen((const char *)cipherIv);
    char hex_iv[(lenIv*2)+1];
    char2hex((char *)cipherIv, hex_iv);

    size_t cipherSize = strlen((const char *)cipherText);
    unsigned char *decoded_data = b64_decode((const char*)cipherText, cipherSize);

    int lenData = strlen((const char *)decoded_data);
    char *hexcipherText;
    hexcipherText = bin2hex(decoded_data, lenData);

    CCCryptorStatus status;
    int len = strlen((const char *)hexcipherText) / 2;
    unsigned char clearText[len];
    unsigned char decodedCipherText[len];
    unsigned char decodedKey[len];
    unsigned char decodedIv[len];
    size_t nDecrypted;
    int i;

    decode(decodedKey, (const char *)hex_key);
    decode(decodedCipherText, (const char *)hexcipherText);
    decode(decodedIv, (const char *)hex_iv);

    status = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, decodedKey, kCCKeySizeAES128, decodedIv, decoded_data, len, clearText, sizeof(clearText), &nDecrypted);

    if (status != kCCSuccess) 
    {
        printf("CCCrypt() failed with error %d\n", status);
    }

    int extraInfo = strlen((const char *)clearText);
    char* toReturn = malloc(extraInfo + 1);

    strcpy(toReturn, (const char *)clearText);
    strcat(toReturn, "\0");
    
    return toReturn;
}
```

Note the base64 encode & decode function (b64_encode, b64_decode):

```
#ifdef b64_USE_CUSTOM_MALLOC
extern void* b64_malloc(size_t);
#endif

#ifdef b64_USE_CUSTOM_REALLOC
extern void* b64_realloc(void*, size_t);
#endif

int bufc = 0;

char* b64_buf_malloc()
{
    char* buf = b64_malloc(B64_BUFFER_SIZE);
    bufc = 1;
    return buf;
}

char* b64_buf_realloc(unsigned char* ptr, size_t size)
{
    if (size > bufc * B64_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        while (size > bufc * B64_BUFFER_SIZE) bufc++;
        char* buf = b64_realloc(ptr, B64_BUFFER_SIZE * bufc);
        if (!buf) return NULL;
        return buf;
    }

    return (char *)ptr;
}

/* Encode in b64 */

char *b64_encode(const unsigned char *src, size_t len)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char *enc = NULL;
  size_t size = 0;
  unsigned char buf[4];
  unsigned char tmp[3];

  enc = (char *) b64_buf_malloc();
  if (NULL == enc) { return NULL; }

  while (len--) 
  {
    tmp[i++] = *(src++);

    if (3 == i) 
    {
      buf[0] = (tmp[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
      buf[1] = ((tmp[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((tmp[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
      buf[2] = ((tmp[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((tmp[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
      buf[3] = tmp[2] & 0x3f;

      enc = (char *) b64_buf_realloc((unsigned char *)enc, size + 4);
      for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
      {
        enc[size++] = b64_table[buf[i]];
      }

      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i > 0) 
  {
    for (j = i; j < 3; ++j) 
    {
      tmp[j] = '\0';
    }

    buf[0] = (tmp[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
    buf[1] = ((tmp[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((tmp[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
    buf[2] = ((tmp[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((tmp[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
    buf[3] = tmp[2] & 0x3f;

    for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); ++j) 
    {
      enc = (char *) b64_buf_realloc((unsigned char *)enc, size + 1);
      enc[size++] = b64_table[buf[j]];
    }

    while ((i++ < 3)) 
    {
      enc = (char *) b64_buf_realloc((unsigned char *)enc, size + 1);
      enc[size++] = '=';
    }
  }

  enc = (char *) b64_buf_realloc((unsigned char *)enc, size + 1);
  enc[size] = '\0';

  return enc;
}

/* Decode b64 */

unsigned char *b64_decode(const char *src, size_t len) 
{
  return b64_decode_ex(src, len, NULL);
}

unsigned char *b64_decode_ex(const char *src, size_t len, size_t *decsize) 
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int l = 0;
  size_t size = 0;
  unsigned char *dec = NULL;
  unsigned char buf[3];
  unsigned char tmp[4];

  dec = (unsigned char *) b64_buf_malloc();
  if (NULL == dec) { return NULL; }

  while (len--) 
  {
    if ('=' == src[j]) { break; }
    if (!(isalnum(src[j]) || '+' == src[j] || '/' == src[j])) { break; }

    tmp[i++] = src[j++];

    if (4 == i) 
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
      {
        for (l = 0; l < 64; ++l) 
        {
          if (tmp[i] == b64_table[l]) 
          {
            tmp[i] = l;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      buf[0] = (tmp[0] << 2) + ((tmp[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
      buf[1] = ((tmp[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((tmp[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
      buf[2] = ((tmp[2] & 0x3) << 6) + tmp[3];

      dec = (unsigned char *) b64_buf_realloc(dec, size + 3);
      if (dec != NULL)
      {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        {
          dec[size++] = buf[i];
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        return NULL;
      }

      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i > 0) 
  {
    for (j = i; j < 4; ++j) 
    {
      tmp[j] = '\0';
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j) 
    {
        for (l = 0; l < 64; ++l) 
        {
          if (tmp[j] == b64_table[l]) 
          {
            tmp[j] = l;
            break;
          }
        }
    }

    buf[0] = (tmp[0] << 2) + ((tmp[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
    buf[1] = ((tmp[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((tmp[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
    buf[2] = ((tmp[2] & 0x3) << 6) + tmp[3];

    dec = (unsigned char *)b64_buf_realloc(dec, size + (i - 1));
    
    if (dec != NULL)
    {
      for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); ++j) 
      {
        dec[size++] = buf[j];
      }
    } 
    else 
    {
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  dec = (unsigned char *)b64_buf_realloc(dec, size + 1);

  if (dec != NULL)
  {
    dec[size] = '\0';
  } 
  else 
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (decsize != NULL) 
  {
    *decsize = size;
  }

  return dec;
}
```

Also note the bin2hex & char2hex function:

```
/* Char to Hex conversion */

void char2hex(char* input, char* output)
{
    int loop;
    int i; 
    
    i=0;
    loop=0;
    
    while(input[loop] != '\0')
    {
        sprintf((char*)(output+i),"%02X", input[loop]);
        loop+=1;
        i+=2;
    }
    output[i++] = '\0';
}

/* Bin to Hex conversion */

static char hexconvtab[] = "0123456789abcdef";

static char* bin2hex(const unsigned char *old, const size_t oldlen)
{
    char *result = (char*) malloc(oldlen * 2 + 1);
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = j = 0; i < oldlen; i++) 
    {
        result[j++] = hexconvtab[old[i] >> 4];
        result[j++] = hexconvtab[old[i] & 15];
    }
    result[j] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

**Now, the PHP Code:**

```
/* Encrypt text */

function encRijndael($text, $key, $iv)
{
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($text) % $block);
    $text .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return base64_encode($crypttext);
}

/* Decrypt Text */

function decRijndael($encrypted, $key, $iv)
{
    $iv_utf = mb_convert_encoding($iv, 'UTF-8');
    $toreturn = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_utf);
    $toreturn = filter_var($toreturn, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
    return $toreturn;
}
```

I learned this code reading the book **O'Reilly, Hacking and Securing iOS Applications** from Jonathan Zdziarski.