# Objective-c AES128 encrypt

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I try to encrypt `NSString` with this class

```
#import "NSData+AES.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (AES)

- (NSData *)AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return [self AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:key iv:nil];
}

- (NSData *)AES128DecryptedDataWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return [self AES128DecryptedDataWithKey:key iv:nil];
}

- (NSData *)AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    return [self AES128Operation:kCCEncrypt key:key iv:iv];
}

- (NSData *)AES128DecryptedDataWithKey:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    return [self AES128Operation:kCCDecrypt key:key iv:iv];
}

- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}

@end
```

I use this code for that:

```
//This is MD5 key
NSString *key = @"7046dd94480f28dbf4b2e3cb6fa3864a";

NSData *plainDataEmail = [@"app@cfd.com" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedDataEmail = [plainDataEmail AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:key];
NSString *encryptedStringEmail = [encryptedDataEmail base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

encryptedStringEmail is:

```
JXf7l5dH3qaYvudxCzE98w==
```

Now I'm checking same details on [this site](http://aesencryption.net/),
and the reason is:

```
gnZZGbRaVtCG8Z8Xf732Cw==
```

Please tell me what is the problem in my Objective-c code

Comment: My mistake, I edited the links

Comment: Does the code produce the same JXf7l5dH3qaYvudxCzE98w== everytime in this case?

Comment: Yes same result

Comment: Edited, Now is it ok?

Comment: Have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997088/i-want-to-create-aes-128-using-cfb-encryption-with-no-padding-in-objective-c/37019462#37019462

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things going on here. Almost every step looks like it's wrong to some extent. I can walk through the, but this whole scheme is very insecure. My recommendation, unless you need specifically to match aesencryption.net, is to use a cross-platform, secure format like [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor).

Short version: there is no universally accepted way to use AES. You must know precisely how both sides have implemented their formats and make them match. aesencryption.net doesn't explain their approach (the code samples don't seem to match each other or the website tool). It is very difficult to use AES correctly, so almost any arbitrarily chosen approach will be very insecure.

You have a key assumption that is incorrect: that plaintext encrypted using the same key should always generate the same cipher text. In a secure scheme, this should *never* be true. (If you were using the tools you're using correctly, then you would get matching output, but that's because they're insecure implementations.) Except in rare circumstances where you need reproducibility and intentionally sacrifice security for it, there should be at least one random element in the scheme that causes every encryption to be unique. In the above code, that random element should be the IV. You should be generating a random IV and passing it to the encryptor.

While you're expecting 128-bit encryption, your key is actually 256 bits long. You probably think that the first byte of your key is 0x70, but that's not correct. It's 0x37, which is the UTF-8 encoding of "7". You're passing a string, and it's just being UTF-8 encoded, and then truncated (or zero-filled) to be 16 bytes. (This is one of the key reasons this ObjC code is so insecure.)

It's unclear what aesencryption.net is doing to the key; they don't show their code, and their code examples aren't clear. Their Java example hashes the key, but I don't think their PHP code does. The way the site behaves, I don't think it hashes, but its behavior is kind of weird. Keys 33 characters long encrypt exactly the same as 32 characters, so it's clearly truncating. But it's truncating to 32 bytes, not 16 bytes, even for 128-bit keys. So that's all very weird.

Finally, the ObjC code is using ECB mode, which is pretty much the worst mode you can pick for general purpose encryption. There are some very specific cases where it's useful, but this isn't one of them. It's not obvious what aesencryption.net is using, though their code examples do use ECB.

Answer (score 0):

Your links aren't working correctly.

I have run into a similar issue in the past. I suspect that the `AES128EncryptedDataWithKey` method is converting your key, which is an `NSString` to binary using a different method or different encoding than the site you attempted to link.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I edited the question again